# TypeError: tableObj.appendChild is not a function

Tags: javascript, mysql, jsp

```
var oTable;
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadSubMenus();
});

function loadSubMenus() {
    var resultStringX = $.ajax({
            type : "POST", 
            url : "getSubMenuList", 
            dataType : 'text', 
            async : false 
    }).responseText;
    resultStringX = $.trim(resultStringX);
    var o = JSON.parse(resultStringX);
    var idArray = new Array();
    var nameArray = new Array();
    idArray = o.result.subMenuId;
    nameArray = o.result.subMenuName;

    var tableObj = $("#tableId").val();
    var colCount = 0;
    var trObj = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++) {
        var tdObj = document.createElement("td");
        var inputElem = document.createElement("input");
        inputElem.type = "checkbox";
        inputElem.setAttribute("id", "id_"+i);
        inputElem.setAttribute("value", idArray[i]);
        inputElem.style.marginTop = "-1px";
        var spanObj = document.createElement("span");
        spanObj.innerHTML = nameArray[i];
        tdObj.appendChild(inputElem);
        tdObj.appendChild(spanObj);
        trObj.appendChild(tdObj);
        colCount++;
        if (colCount == 5) {
            tableObj.appendChild(trObj);
            trObj = "";
            trObj = document.createElement("tr");
            colCount = 0;
        }
        if (idArray.length < 5) {
            if ((idArray.length - 1) == i) {
                tableObj.appendChild(trObj);
            }
        }
    }
    if(idArray.length/5>0){
        tableObj.appendChild(trObj);
    }
    document.getElementById("subMenuCount").value=idArray.length;
}
```

am not getting output..
i want to load menu n sub-menu from the database
what is error am nt able to get pls help me
how to solve this.
what i have to do..
what is the error
in another jsp page i created "tableid" so there i defined td

Answer (score 0):

`tableObj` is not a DOM element. It is the value of `$("#tableId").val()`. Probably you need to create it also as a DOM element:

```
var tableObj = document.createElement("table");
...
```